# Custom Matcher for "calls method on object"

Tags: ruby, rspec

Given a method like:

```rb
class MyClass
  def method_that_calls_stuff
    method2("some value")
  end
end
```

I'd like to define an expectation like:

```rb
my_object = MyClass.new
expect{ my_object.method_that_calls_stuff }.to call(:method2).on(my_object).with("some value")
```

I know I can achieve the same thing using `rspec-mocks`, but I don't like that syntax as well.

How would I define a matcher like that (or even better, has someone already written one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new syntax though you can get

```
instance = MyClass.new
expect(instance).to receive(:method2).with("some value")
instance.method_that_calls_stuff
```

but if you really want that matcher, you can do

```
RSpec::Matchers.define(:call) do |method|
  match do |actual|
    expectation = expect(@obj).to receive(method)
    if @args
      expectation.with(@args)
    end
    actual.call
    true
  end

  chain(:on) do |obj|
    @obj = obj
  end

  chain(:with) do |args|
    @args = args
  end

  def supports_block_expectations?
    true
  end
end
```

Notice that `with` is optional as you may want to call a method without any args.

You can get full info on how to build custom matchers [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-1/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher), and fluent interface/chaining [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-1/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher-with-fluent-interface) and the block support [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-1/docs/custom-matchers/define-a-matcher-supporting-block-expectations). If you browse around you can find how to add nice error messages and such, which always come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that `method2` is being called on some object(is it being called implicitly?). But I usually write it like this:

```
it 'should call method2 with some value' do
  MyClass.should_receive(:method2).with("some value") 
  MyClass.method_that_calls_stuff
  # or
  # @my_object.should_receive(:method2).with("some value")
  # @my_object.method_that_calls_stuff
end
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the syntax I use as well. I'm wanting a Matcher that will let me set the expectation and call the method in a single statement.